# How to Programatically Access Google Spreadsheet File Name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Question is simple. How to get Name (File name in Google Drive) of a spreadsheet using spreadsheet identifier. If you want to know why I need it, you may please continue reading further.

I have created two type of spreadsheets to manage my financial books with my friends, family and business.

Type 1: A book that contains all transactions with a specific person and tells Amount owed or amount lended. I have about 15 of such sheets. Check this screenshot:

[image: Single Account]

Type 2: A sheet named as investments. It fetches data from all other sheets using Sheet Identifier and displays total amount invested or borrowed. Check this screenshot:

[image: Investments]

In Type 2 sheet, I have programmed and made everything automated. You just need to paste Identifier of any new Spreadsheet in G Column and you're done. Only one thing is Killing me. I am unable to fetch name of the spreadsheet using Identifier. I fetched all records of the sheet using IMPORTRANGE Method, just the file name is not getting fetched. I tried plenty of functions.

Yellow Columns denotes Automatic Columns. I just want to make Column B automatic in case of Type 2 Spreadsheet. It should contain Spreadsheet File Name fetched through Sheet Identifier, same as I fetched all rows of multiple sheets & made calculations within Type 2 sheet. Thanks for considering to help me out.

Comment: Please include more details (see [mcve] to learn about what it's expected).

Comment: The question is simple. I want to get file name of google spreadsheets using sheet ID. Code given by Bardy is facing permission issue.

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want the name of a Sheets file from the Sheets ID? How about:

```
var spreadsheetId = 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID';
var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getName();
```

Comment: You got it right. I am checking whether it works and would update in a moment. Thanks!

Comment: It throws an error: 

You do not have permission to perform that action. (line 3).

I am passing a static Sheet ID. 
I am not even able to fetch name of the file I am writing code on. I tried another thing. I executed the code in script editor. It asked permission that this code wants to manage your spreadsheets. I allowed it. Still no luck.

Comment: Please give us your code in the question, so we can see how you wrote it. Considering some things I have read on SE, I would not be surprised if you actually wrote `var spreadsheetId = 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID';` in the code

Comment: I am a developer & I understand codes :) I am just new to google sheets & javascript both and stuck on this. Initially I passed static value in spreadsheetId variable. Check this
`function GetSheetName() {
var spreadsheetId = '1DMwEWSwV-E_vA1GGhWCL8oD6U4g0ze7FjlW6kDIzqEA';
var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getName();
return sheetName;
}`

Next thing I tried is passing sheet ID as parameter.  Check this:

`function GetSheetName(Id) {
return SpreadsheetApp.openById(Id).getName();
}`

Nothing helps. Seems permission issue with getName method.

Comment: @KunalKhanna : add the code to the question, describe how do you ran it and if the related files are shared with you.